# Send command using Node-RED v.0.18.7

Tags: node-red, watson-iot

I want to send command to Raspberry Pi, so I deployed the watson iot input and output node. And I referenced the last 2017 document. However, in this version I used (Node-RED v.0.18.7), it is different example. (without output type and input type in watson Node). What I add additionally? I attached my configuration.

[image]

Give your advice. Thanks.

Comment: also post reference 2017 document link

Answer (score 4):

There are two different Watson IoT node modules:

- [node-red-contrib-scx-ibmiotapp](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-scx-ibmiotapp) - this provides Application access to your Watson IoT service and can be used to receive Data events from Devices/Gateways and to send Commands back to them
- [node-red-contrib-ibm-watson-iot](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-ibm-watson-iot) - this provides nodes to connect to Watson IoT as a Device or Gateway - sending Data events and receiving commands.

The '2017 document' you have shared is using the `node-red-contrib-scx-ibmiotapp` module. You have installed the `node-red-contrib-ibm-watson-iot` module.

You need to use `node-red-contrib-scx-ibmiotapp`.